# How to rotate an object around another object's local axis?

Tags: constraints, axis, transform-orientation

I am making skyboxes for a game, and would like to prototype the skyboxes' rotation angle in Blender. I made a simple vertical mesh line that represents the rotation axis of the skybox, and I would like to be able to rotate the skybox along the mesh line's local Z axis, no matter how I rotate the mesh line itself.
[image]

Here you can see if I rotate the mesh line on the X axis, and make a new custom orientation from it, the skybox rotates around the mesh line as expected, but I would like this to be dynamic, so I can animate the skybox rotating, and when I rotate the mesh line, the skybox rotation adapts accordingly.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Rotation on local axes can always be achieved by pressing R and then twice the key for the axis: R, Z, Z to rotate on local axis. Pressing Z once is global Z axis, pressing Z again is local Z axis, pressing Z a third time gets you back to global rotation. Or to generally rotate on local axes with pressing the key only once, you can change the _Transformation Orientation_ to _Local_ instead of the default _Global_ at the top menu of the _3D Viewport_. If you do this, pressing Z once rotates on local Z and pressing it twice rotates on global Z.

Comment: Oh, I'm stupid, you want it for animation. I'll write an answer.

Comment: I finally understand the question: the simple parenting doesn't work because you don't want the sphere to follow when the rotation axis is moved. Therefore this solution is wrong: https://i.imgur.com/r09WqPD.gif

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie no, just simple animation of the sphere (animating euler Z rotation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for driven axis-angle rotation.  I don't think this is doable with constraints only, because of the way that Blenders handles rotation in its constraints (it decomposes rotation into Euler triplets and adds/subtracts them, which isn't really right.)

Start by making an empty at the world origin and empty.001 at world Z = 1.  Parent empty.001 to empty.  Change your skybox rotation mode to axis-angle, then create drivers for its X, Y, and Z rotation.  It's X rotation should equal the world space X location transform channel of empty.001, Y should be the Y location, and Z should be the Z location.  Keyframe W to 0 at the beginning of your rotation and 360 degrees at the end of your rotation.

[image]

Now see what happens when you rotate empty.  Its child follows, which changes the axis along which your skybox rotates.

[image]

You can change the axis of rotation ussed by your skybox to any axis desired by rotating the parent empty.

Comment: Hah, that is perfect! It's doing exactly what I need. Thank you very much! And thanks Gordon too, I hope you didn't really go crazy :D